# making the embed change color during a time discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, embed

```
    case 'test':
      let timed = "10s"
      const tests = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("tets")
      .setColor('#000000')

      message.channel.send(tests);
      setTimeout(function(){
      tests.setColor('#5e4242')
      }, ms(timed));

      break;
```

so im trying to make the embed's color change after 10 secs,this is a test command so its called test.I tried many ways and i searched google and it showed this so i decided to try it and it does completly nothing.I use richembed because when i use messagemebed it says client error

Comment: Edit the message with the same embed with a different colour. `MessageEmbed` may not be working because you aren’t using Discord.js v12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set the message you send into a variable and then edit that message.

```
  let timed = "10s"
  const tests = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("tets")
  .setColor('#000000')

  const res = await message.channel.send(tests);
  setTimeout(function(){
     tests.setColor('#5e4242');
     res.edit(tests);
  }, ms(timed));
```

Should also note, await only works in an async function

Answer (score 1):

Setting the color after you sent the message will edit the object but it won't edit that message, you can edit the message with the same message object but after changing the color aswell

```
    let timed = "10s"
      const tests = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("tets")
      .setColor('#000000');

    var testMsg = message.channel.send(tests).then(
      setTimeout(function(){
         tests.setColor('#5e4242');
         testMsg.edit(tests); // edit the message with the same object but different color
      }, ms(timed));
)

      break;
```

Comment: This will not work. tests.edit(tests), tests is not the message, only the embed, so you would need to set message.channel.send into a variable and then edit that. Also should note message.channel.send is async.

Comment: Yes you are right, I will update my answer, thank you!

Comment: That will still not work, message.channel.send returns a promise, so you need to wait for it to resolve, you can either use await or .then()

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **V12** version

```
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#ffffff')
    .setTitle('I am a colour-changing embed')

    let msg = await message.channel.send(embed)
setTimeout(() => {
     embed.setColor('#5e4242');
     msg.edit(embed);
  }, /*Delay*/);
```

This code makes a new embed and then creates a *let* variable which the message is sent with [kinda like sending the message with a tag]. Then it takes the embed variable edits the color and edits the previous message after a delay.

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider [Explaining how this answers the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)